# Dragging and dropping sword in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I am developing a 2d game using unreal engine 4 in which the user drags and drops a sword.I want the sword to follow the position of my finger.At the moment, when I drag the sword, it moves at an offset from my finger.The game has been packaged to an pad and I have set up the functionality using blueprints.

Pseudo code:

```
On Drag (){ 

finger position = sword position on screen

on drop = finger position on release from screen = position of sword

}
```

How do I make the sword follow the position of my finger as I drag it?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen documention? [Creating Drag and Drop UI](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/UMG/HowTo/DragAndDrop)

Comment: I have seen the documentation yes. However I am still struggling to find the solution for a touch screen device.